# Lan DNS not working after reinstall of Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns

I upgrade my Ubuntu desktop to 13.10. When I say upgrade I mean installed on a new partition from scratch (old partition is available if

To the problem:
I'm trying to ping a host (Drobo-FS server) by it's host name. I get "Unknown Host". However pinging from another computer on the same lan - works fine (a laptop with 12.04 lts).

for that matter every ping from the 13.10 to the local lan by hostname fails, ping with ip works.

I don't have a local DNS server but somehow all the other computers in the network find each other by host name - only this new one fails...

help appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see it now the problem is you're not getting a search domain from your dns-server (presumably your router).

Your resolv.conf should look like this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) 
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN 
nameserver 192.168.1.254         # <-- could also be 127.0.1.1, does not matter
search fritz.box                 # <-- THIS IS IMPORTANT
```

Normally with a ping the OS appends the search-string after the hostname to search on its internal network. (You'll see that `ping drobo-fs.domain.ext` does work.) You should have gotten the `domain.ext` automatically from the dns-server.

Now you'll need to determine what the `domain.ext` is in your case. You could try `nslookup x.x.x.x` where `x.x.x.x` is your dns-server (router?, in my example `192.168.1.254`). For me it gave a `name = fritz.box.` at the end. (where `fritz.box` is the `domain.ext`)

Now you can add this yourself by adding it in the connection-settings like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5yMb12j.png]

After that both `ping drobo-fs.domain.ext` and `ping drobo-fs` should work.

---

Old answer (for reference):

Why not just have the line `hosts: files dns` in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` ?

Remove the `mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]` and `mdns4` if you don't have a working mdns-setup in your network.

You could also try `[NOTFOUND=continue]` instead of `[NOTFOUND=return]` if you **do** have a mdns-setup in your network.

Comment: it is /etc/nsswitch.conf. edited my question. After updating the file - what services should I restart?

Comment: That depends on what service exactly is using this file. Normally the file is read again but if some service has it in memory then a reboot is required. (or you need to know the service) See [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/76853/nsswitch-conf-is-there-a-daemon-i-need-to-restart)

Comment: OK. Changed the file. Rebooted. Still doens't work.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a `search lan` line in your `resolv.conf`? Try putting a `#` before it (just for testing). No reboot necessary.

Comment: this is my resolv.conf:# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1

Comment: O, i need to look into resolvconf (which generated this one). But does `ping hostname.` work? (note the dot after hostname) And does the `nslookup hostname` work normally?

Comment: ping host. -> doesn't work. nslookup host returns: Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find drobo-fs: NXDOMAIN
Is it the "normal way"?

Comment: I take it you **are** running your own dns/bind server (on `127.0.1.1`)? Does `ping google.com` work? (and `nslookup google.com`) If you don't get results you'll need to change your dns server to that of your router/server.

Comment: I'm not running anything I am aware of. How do I check that. ping and nslookup work great. My eth is configured manually with ip and dns address is the router (also the gateway)

Comment: I've disabled it by commenting dns=dnsmasq in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (and reboot). Now I get my expected dns server in /etc/resolv.conf and indeed no process listens on port 53. But still no ping HOST...

Comment: I fired up a VM with Ubuntu and see lots has changed. Ubuntu is running its own dns (of sorts). My `resolv.conf` is also generated **but** has a line `search fritz.box`. That one is missing for you. It is used to append after `drobo-fs` to get a qualified name. I'm not exactly sure yet how to configure that search line. Do you know your domain name? What is the result of `dnsdomainname -A`? (capital A!)

Comment: `dnsdomainname -A` returns empty line. I have a workgroup defined but no domain name

Comment: Yeah, but your router (which i presume is the main dns server) should have one. For me it's `fritz.box`. And with the  search line i can do `ping hostname` but without i need to do `ping hostname.fritz.box` to get a ping. (also for that name is automatically taken from the dns-server) Still not sure why yours is not.

Comment: You should get your domain name with `nslookup x.x.x.x` where the `x.x.x.x` is your (new) dns-server. At the end you get a `name = xxx`.

Comment: I added some new information, at the top of my answer, as how i see it now. (for me it's bedtime so i'll see how it worked out in the morning)

Comment: thanks for all your efforts. you are right - my router is my dns server. Here's the output of nslookup to it:Server:         192.168.2.1
Address:        192.168.2.1#53 ** server can't find router: NXDOMAIN
I think the problem lies in the diffrences between 12.04 (my old desktop and the 13.10). Something must have changed in the defaults cause all the other computers on the network work the same. And even the 13.10 can talk netbios to the server

Comment: Are you setting a static ip address or do you have DHCP enabled on your PC? If it is static try setting it to DHCP. Also, could you check on the other PC's what the `domain.ext` (search domain) is? For Windows you can do `ipconfig` and it is the `Connection-specific DNS Suffix`. For Linux the search line in `cat /etc/resolv.conf` or `dnsdomainname -A`.

Comment: I've changed the question because I now understand (thanks to your help) that the problem is dns at general in the local lan - see my updated question. +1 for the effort.

Comment: You didn't answer on my previous comment about static ip or dynamic. (If static you wouldn't get the search domain from your dhcp/router and you'll need to set it manually) Also did you find the `domain.ext` on the others computers? It's important to know because if others have a `domain.ext` then you're not getting the name from the dhcp/router. So does the laptop (12.04) have a search line in `resolv.conf`?

Comment: it's dynamic. In other computers and in this one `resolv.conf` says `search local` as expected. `dnsdomain` returns empty string (in other computer it returns hostname.local). In the working computers resolv.conf also includes the outer dns servers and in the 13.10 one I only get 127.0.0.1. this is the expected behaviour since 13.10

Comment: Another update. Trying to return everything back to the default, I can now get ping mylaptop.local from the 13.10. I've also to drobo-fs resolv.conf `search local` and `domain local` and now when pinging it I get: PING drobo-fs.local (169.254.133.188) 56(84) bytes of data. Which is totally wrong of course...

Comment: FIXED: I added to the drobo-fs my providers dns server and now everything works. Thanks for pointing me in the direction

Answer (score 0):

Having wins in /etc/nsswitch.conf should work.  I know it works on my network where we run a wins.  But if the entry you are looking for is not in wins, then of course it wouldn't work.  So, "wins" is the right answer, now you just need to make sure the client is in wins.

Comment: pinging from my laptop works... and pinging from the previous installation also worked... and the host does answer to the smbclient -L command. So I think it should work as well from the new isntallation